# Extend a standard command

Tags: macros

What I want to do is the following:
whenever my code says `\begin{lstlisting}` I want it to be `\begin{lstlisting}[language=GLSL]` instead.

What I tried was inserting `\renewcommand{\begin{lstlisting}}{\begin{lstlisting}[language=GLSL]}` into the preamble of my document. But it seems to cause an infinite loop when compiling.

My question is: How could I get what I want without replacing every `\begin{lstlisting}` in the whole document?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this particular instance, the usual redefinition tricks will likely not help you. (`lstlisting` needs to know when to stop the verbatim reading, so it needs to know what its environment is called.) 
The following is taken from the manual:

> 4.16 Environments
>
> If you want to define your own pretty-printing environments, try the following command. The syntax comes from LATEX’s
>   \newenvironment.

```
\lstnewenvironment {name}[number][opt. default arg.] {starting code} {ending code}
```

> As a simple example we could
>   just select a particular language.

```
lstnewenvironment{pascal}
{\lstset{language=pascal}} {}
```

> Doing other things is as easy, for
>   example, using more keys and adding an optional argument to adjust
>   settings each listing:

```
\lstnewenvironment{pascalx}[1][]
{\lstset{language=pascal,numbers=left,numberstyle=\tiny,float,#1}} {}
```

ETA: And also, if I remember correctly, just saying `\lstset{language=GLSL}` will affect all further listings.

Comment: The `\lstset{language=GLSL}` worked. Thanks a lot.