# Add prefix command(s) - counter of todos

Tags: macros, counters, todonotes

I would like to see the number of `todos` I have left. Therefor I tried to redefine the `todo` command as follows:

```
\newcounter{todocounter}
\renewcommand{\todo}[2][]{\stepcounter{todocounter}\todo[#1]{#2}}
```

However this seems to cause an infinite loop (the todo inside the definition seems to use the todo in the declaration). Searching only yielded [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44403/extend-a-standard-command) which does not help in my case. Is there a trick to make this work? (etoolbox/ can I use some expansion time wizardry/would an alias help)

I do not want to replace all `todo`s with `numberedTodo` or similar.

Comment: You can see this question : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88001/when-to-use-letltxmacro (it isn't a duplicate in my opinion, though).

Comment: @T.Verron: thanks, that was the hint I was looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `T.Verron`s [hint](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88001/when-to-use-letltxmacro) it becomes obvious. The infinite recursion can be solved by creating a copy of the macro with a different name.

```
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
...
\newcounter{todocounter}
\LetLtxMacro{\oldTodo}{\todo}
\renewcommand{\todo}[2][]{\stepcounter{todocounter}\oldTodo[#1]{#2}}
...
\thetodocounter
```

If anyone finds this and wants to print the total number of todos before the end of the document check out this answer: [How to display the final value of a counter at the beginning of a document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34789/how-to-display-the-final-value-of-a-counter-at-the-beginning-of-a-document)